# What is Teacher Helping technique?

Tags: rnn, lstm, gan

I read [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.01399.pdf) paper, but I am having trouble understanding what Teacher Helping technique (page 3) is in context of RNN.

Can someone explain to me what it is? Please assume I don't have much experience in statistics. I'll be glad if this explanation would be as simple as possible (I'll be even more grateful for some example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normal RNNs, you can train using either back-propagation through time (BPTT) or teacher forcing. With BPTT the network receives as input for each time step the output of the previous time step. In teacher forcing, the network receives the gold data tokens directly; this induces *exposure bias* on the trained network.

With textual GANs, you normally don't feed the gold data to the generator, because the generator is generating the sequence so there is no gold data to use.

In the article you refer, they are taking subsequences from real data, feeding them to the generator and having it only generate the final token. Then the discriminator receives the concatenation of the real sequence prefix and the generated final token. This is what they call "teacher helping".

Comment: This paper mentions Teacher *Helping*. Are they the same thing?

Comment: Please read carefully the last paragraph of the answer, especially the last sentence, where I make the connection with teacher helping.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread that. Thank you for explanation!